# Geospatial datafile for Euroregions

Tags: geospatial, europe, data

Does there exist a geospatial datafile with the shapes/boundaries of Euroregions? As explained in sources like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euroregion), Euroregions are zones within the European Union where local governments separated by a border have established a formal arrangement for cooperating on some issue. The Association of European Border Regions lists the [names and involved jurisdictions](https://www.aebr.eu/members/), but I cannot find a geospatial version of this set. If this does not exist, any suggestions on a good geospatial data source for all European subnational administrative divisions from which one could manually merge the shapes of localities across countries into Euroregions? There seem to be a bunch, and I am not sure which is the definitive source.

[image] [Source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-map-of-Euroregions-Source-http-wwwaebreu_fig1_267727234)